# creating an initialized string in java given input parameters

Tags: java

is there a nice way for creating a string initialized with a number of characters given an int (counter) and the character to set.
Simply put I would like a method that returns "#,#,#,#,#" when passed 5 and # as parameter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) utility in the [Apache Commons lang library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
String myString = StringUtils.repeat("#", ",", 5);
```

If you only want the characters (and not the comma separators), it is just:

```
String myString = StringUtils.repeat("#", 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to write a method for this:

```
public static String createPlaceholderString(char placeholder, int count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(count * 2 - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i!= 0) {
            builder.append(',');
        }
        builder.append(placeholder);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

(Note that we can initialize the builder with exactly the right size of buffer as we know how big it will be.)

You *could* use something like `Strings.repeat` from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
String text = Strings.repeat("#,", count - 1) + "#";
```

Or even more esoterically:

```
String text = Joiner.on(',').join(Iterables.limit(Iterables.cycle("#"), count));
```

... but personally I'd probably stick with the method.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid exactly that.

Comment: @AssafAdato: Why? It's a 9 line method which you can write once and then reuse from everywhere you need it.

Comment: it's not about the implementation complexity at all, a simple method can handle it as you mentioned. however, it looks like a method that may already be available in one of my project's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public String buildString(int nbr, String repeat){
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i=0; i>nbr; i++){
     builder.append(repeat);
     if(i<(nbr-1))
         builder.append(",");
  }


   return builder.toString();
}
```